# MetadataType missing assembly reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;




  namespace yplaylist.Models
  {
     [MatadataType(typeof(Song_Validation))]
     public partial class Song
     {

     }

     public class Song_Validation
     {



     }
 }
```

MetadataType is highlighted saying that it could not be found missing a using directive or assembly reference? what am I missing?

Comment: Is this your exact code? You mispelled MetadataType - you have it as MatadataType. Could this be your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you copied your code directly into your question, but you have a spelling error in your code:

It should be:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Song_Validation))]
public partial class Song
{ 
}
```

You spelled it as `MatadataType`.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing assembly `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` in reference

Comment: I have added this dll and it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Ensure right versions of dll, and you compiling code with right .net framework version